# Port forwarding no longer working

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, isp, pfsense

I have a pfsense router setup and have port forwarded a couple of ports. After last week I could no longer connect to my openVPN and I realized that my ip had been changed and I could no longer connect via openVPN. After changing the pfsense to a regular router trying unplugging the pfsense for a longer time and then plugging it in again but it all ends with the same problem.

One thing I noticed that might be the case is that the ip address on the router is different from the one I get when I check online. Don't know if this is the reason behind it but it is an idea that I have not been able to solve. It kinda acts as it were cgnat but the address on the router starts with 146 and the one online starts with 185. I have also talked to my ISP and they told me that nothing seems to be wrong on their end.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Yes I got a dynamic ip assigned(used to have cgnat) from ISP. It acts just as if it were cgnated but I doubt that is the case as I currently have 2 different public addresses pointing my way so it would be kind of pointless for them I guess

Comment: Is this possible when the IP address on my router is 146.247.255.105? If I'm not mistaken a public address like this can't be in a cgnat pool

Comment: Viasat but I doubt they own the IP addresses themself, it should probably be owned by either Telia or IP only but I am not certain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I called my ISP for the fifth time and they confessed that it was a common problem within my city Network and they would fix it in a couple of days!